# Ptolemy Trig/Geometry Help Please

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

For this problem, I need to find a bunch of values for this semicircle, and use the methods of Ptolemy to find a value for sin 18.  This is for a low level math history class, and I'm bot good with geometry (I really don't know how to find chord values) and I would appreciate your help on this problem.  Thanks.

To find the value for sin 18, Ptolemy used the following theorem: ABC is a semi- 
     circle with center D; BD is perpendicular to AC. DC is bisected at E and  EF = EB
     where F is on AD. Then FD has the same length as the side of a regular decagon 
     inscribed in a  circle, and BF has the same length as the side of a regular pentagon 
     inscribed in the circle. Note that F does not bisect AD. We will assume, as Ptolemy 
     did, that the  radius of the circle is 60.

a)  Find the exact values of  DE, BD, BE, FD, and BF.

b)  Use these to find the exact value of sin 18. (Hint: The side of the regular decagon is the chord with central angle of 360/10 = 36)

Note: For this problem, a numerical expression is “exact” if it uses only addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square roots of rational numbers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem#Complement_of_pentagon_chord

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following as thought by Ptolomeo of course, but I tried to be as basic as possible. You have to consider some triangles.

1. The triangle $\Delta BDE$ where $BD=R$ and $DE=R/2$. Then since $BD$ is perpendicular to $DE$ you have that $BE=\sqrt{5}R/2$. (By our other friend Pythagoras)
2. Next you know that $BE=FE$ but $FE=FD+DE$ and therefore $FD=FE-DE=\sqrt{5}R/2-R/2$.
3. Finally consider a decagon inscribed in a circle of radius $R$ with centre $O$. The side of the decagon is what you call chord. Then you know that the side of the decagon inscribed in the circle of radius $R$ is $FD=\sqrt{5}R/2-R/2$. Keeping the notation let $F,D$ be the end-points of the chord. These points of course are in the circle. Now, you can construct the triangle $\Delta OFD$. This is an isosceles triangle with sides $R, R, FD$. note also that the angle at $O$ is $36º$. If you bisect such angle you have now, for example, the triangle $\Delta OFG$ where $G$ is at the middle of $FD$ and the angle at $G$ is $90º$. The angle at $O$ is now $18º$ so you compute $\sin(18º)$ as

$$\sin(18º)=\frac{FG}{R}=\frac{FD/2}{R}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} $$